# AndEngine Physics Box2D - the AnimatedSprite images moves even without any sensor change

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have an AnimatedSprite as a player, and I'm using IAccelerometerListener to move to the player to and fro.
Problem is that even when the device is rested on table without any movement, my player moves upward or toward right.

Can anyone point what I have missed. Below is my code.

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {
.....
physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);


    /** for POTRAIT */
    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int cameraWidth = display.getWidth();
    int cameraHeight = display.getHeight();
    final Shape ground = new Rectangle(0,cameraHeight, CAMERA_WIDTH,0);
    final Shape roof = new Rectangle(0,cameraHeight - (player.getHeight() * 2)  , CAMERA_WIDTH, player.getHeight() / 2);
    final Shape left = new Rectangle(0,0, 2,cameraHeight);
    final Shape right = new Rectangle(cameraWidth , 0, 2, cameraHeight);

    final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 1);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

    this.mMainScene.attachChild(ground);
    this.mMainScene.attachChild(roof);
    this.mMainScene.attachChild(left);
    this.mMainScene.attachChild(right);

    mMainScene.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
    final Body grd = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, player, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

    this.mMainScene.attachChild(player);
    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(player,grd, true, true));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a threshold value and check in onAccelerationChanged method if the x and y values are greater than that threshold, then update your sprite otherwise ignore that update step.
Like:

```
@Override
    public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(pAccelerationData.getX() > THRESHOLD_X || pAccelerationData.getY() > THRESHOLD_Y) {
          // update your sprite now...

        }
    }
```